# Redirect to another page after countdown timer

Tags: html

I have a countdown timer template bootstrap
im setting a timer for the new year, but i would like to make after the time ends the page redirect to another page in my website automatically
here is my js

```
 $(window).load(function(){
     $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
});


function initializeSite() {

    "use strict";


    (function() {
        function centerInit(){

            var sphereContent = $('.sphere'),
                sphereHeight = sphereContent.height(),
                parentHeight = $(window).height(),
                topMargin = (parentHeight - sphereHeight) / 2;

            sphereContent.css({
                "margin-top" : topMargin+"px"
            });

            var heroContent = $('.hero'),
                heroHeight = heroContent.height(),
                heroTopMargin = (parentHeight - heroHeight) / 2;

            heroContent.css({
                "margin-top" : heroTopMargin+"px"
            });

        }

        $(document).ready(centerInit);
        $(window).resize(centerInit);
    })();


    $('#scene').parallax();

};

$(window).load(function(){

    initializeSite();
    (function() {
        setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,0);},0);
    })();

});



$('#countdown').countdown({
    date: "January 1, 2020 00:00:00",
    render: function(data) {
      var el = $(this.el);
      el.empty()

        //.append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.years, 4) + "<span>years</span></div>")
        .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span>ДНЕЙ</span></div>")
        .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>ЧАСЫ</span></div>")
        .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>МИНУТ</span></div>")
        .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>СЕКУНД</span></div>");
    }
});
```

i tried to add

```
if (seconds < 0) {
            // Chnage your redirection link here
            window.location = "#";
        }
```

but the countdown disappear after this code
any help would be appreciated 
*im new coder so if the solution was simple excuse me ))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest is correct... Change:

```
if (seconds < 0) {
   // Chnage your redirection link here
   window.location = "#";
}
```

to

```
if (seconds < 0) {
   //put the page name below (index.html is common, but not for sure. You would know)
   window.location.href = "index.html"; 
}
```

Comment: Nope, didn’t work whenever i add this code the timer totally disappears !

Comment: Yes, the timer probably *would* disappear, because it redirects to another page. The idea is that when the desired time is reached, the page automatically navigates to another page (in this case `index.html`),  as you requested in the question. You have several options: (1) Create a new page (i.e. `timesup.html`) and navigate there `window.location.href = 'timesup.html';`, or (2) Use javascript to pop-up a modal div with a message, or (3) append new content to the current page, or (4) overwrite everything in the `<body>` with a message... So, what precisely do you want to happen at zero secs?